# ¿Como se puede agregar una enumeración o indice a los registros (0,1,2..) que cumplan una condición?

Tags: php, mysql

Algo asi (RowNum)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y como se podrian mostrar el registro con el RowNum que se desee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede lograr mediante la siguiente subconsulta:

```
SELECT * From(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CustomerID ASC) AS 'Row',
  c.IdPedido,c.SalesOrderID,c.OrderDate,c.SalesOrderNumber,c.SubTotal,c.TotalDue
  from Customers c where c.CustomerID = '11000') TB
  where TB.Row = '1'
```